# Iterate a map in a map

Tags: terraform

I have a variable in `tf` declared as an object map that takes a string, and a child map of string values.

```html
variable "apps" {
  type = map(object({
    hits = number,
    id = map(string),
  }))
```

Variable looks like this:

```
 default     = {
test = {
  hits = 1,
  id  = {
    one = "image-1234"
    two = "image-4567"
  }
}
```

In a resource declaration, I need the `hits` variable but also the child keys and values of the `id` map. How can I achieve this?

I have tried many code iterations, but would love to do something like:

`name = id[each.key]` to get the current key

I tried using count and getting a list of keys/values, e.g

I also tried to see if I can get the key value from the map, e.g.:

```
 description  = each.value[currentiteration].Value
```

In other words, I tried lots of combinations, even though the above is not right.

Comment: You need to provide example of the actual variable, and what is your code and what errors do you get.

Comment: Amended the post to include this.

Comment: "I have tried many code iterations," - what exactly did you try? Sorry, your question is not clear as it is unknown what you are doing or want to accomplish.

Comment: added more details.

Comment: Sadly, your code does not help much. What is `var.application_insights_appname`? Its not described in your question nor there are any examples of it.